# How to insert several multiple selection same name into mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

I need to know how Html form several multiple selection same name insert into mysql?? I'll get this problem->[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12LIa.jpg) that all insert into one field ,those score option 1 should be many row,not just one column! I want it like this-->[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7RSw.jpg) Can someone tell me how to do?

I used java(spring)、hibernate、mysql for tools.

**Please help me!!!!**

This is my jsp code:

```
<form id="result" role="form" class="form-inline" action="mature.htm" here`method="post">

 <font size="5"><select name="score" class="form-control input-lg">
                                <option value="1">○</option>
                                <option value="2">△</option>
                                <option value="3">×</option></select>
                        </font>
                <font size="5"><select name="score" class="form-control input-lg">
                                <option value="1">○</option>
                                <option value="2">△</option>
                                <option value="3">×</option></select>
                        </font>
                <font size="5"><select name="score" class="form-control input-lg">
                                <option value="1">○</option>
                                <option value="2">△</option>
                                <option value="3">×</option></select>
                        </font>
```

This is my entity model:

```
 public class Result  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer no;
 private String username;
 private String questionid;
 private String score;

public Result() {
}

public Result(String username, String questionid, String score) {
   this.username = username;
   this.questionid = questionid;
   this.score = score;
}

 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)


@Column(name="no", unique=true, nullable=false)
public Integer getNo() {
    return this.no;
}

public void setNo(Integer no) {
    this.no = no;
}


@Column(name="username", length=45)
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}


@Column(name="questionid", length=255)
public String getQuestionid() {
    return this.questionid;
}

public void setQuestionid(String questionid) {
    this.questionid = questionid;
}


@Column(name="score", length=45)
public String getScore() {
    return this.score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}
```

This is my hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="entity.Result" table="result" catalog="companyresources" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="no" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="no" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="username" type="string">
        <column name="username" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="questionid" type="string">
        <column name="`questionid`" length="255" />
    </property>
    <property name="score" type="string">
        <column name="score" length="45" />
    </property>
</class>
```

This is my java controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/mature",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String create2(@ModelAttribute(value="result")Result e,Result    e2,Model m)
{
   CompanyModel model=new CompanyModel();
   model.create2(e,e2);

    m.addAttribute("list",model.getID());
    m.addAttribute("lst2",model.getAll2());
     m.addAttribute("list",model.getID2());

   return"redirect:question.htm";
}
```